# How can I create a new matrix that from the other's elements?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to pick out the elements which are

(2*pi*k),

where *k=0,1,2,3...* which means integer, and fill them (*i1*) into the other matrix.

But my problem is, I don't know how to make *"k"* be row. (By the way, dividends and divisors are float, so I need to find the approximations and see them as *2*pi*k*).

My code, only can find the elements which are *(2*pi*k)*, but can't order them like if *k=1*, then it will be put into *k=1* row; if *k=2*, then the element should be put into *k=2* row.

For example,

```
A = [2*pi 6 3 4;0.5*pi 0 2;3.1 7 4 8;2*pi 7 2 9;2.6 4*pi 6*pi 0]
```

I want the output to be

```
B = [0 2*pi 4*pi 6*pi;0 2*pi NaN NaN;NaN 2*pi NaN NaN]
```

This is my code:

```
k=0;

for m=380:650;   
   for n=277:600;
      if  abs((rem(abs(i(m,n)),(2*PI)))-(PI))>=3.11;                                 
          k=k+1;
          B(m,k)=i1(m,n); 
       end  
   end
      k=0;
end
```

It can find what I want but they seem not to be ordered the way I want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] the question to contain a small (e.g. 4x5 matrix) example of input and output? That way it will be easier for us to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Please, format your in-line code and structure your question, it will be easier to read. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: Thanks for giving some advice, I've fixed it

Comment: What are `m` and `n` in your code? Where do those numbers come from?

Comment: m and n just represent row and column, I set those numbers to represent the size of the matrix.

Comment: the loop doesn't run because i is not defined, and the first two lines won't run either

Answer (score 0):

As others, I'm a bit unsure what you want. Here's how I understood it and would code it:

1. check whether `(2*pi*k)` is contained in `A`, you want a numerical approach
2. output binary result

here's the code:

```
testPI=@(k) (2*pi*k); %generates 2*pi*k, where k is up to the user
A = [2*pi 6 3 4;0.5*pi 0 2 0;3.1 7 4 8;2*pi 7 2 9;2.6 4*pi 6*pi 0]; %A from example (fixed dimension error)
ismember(A,f(1:10)) %test if k=1:10 is contained in A

ans =

  5×4 logical array

   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0
   0   1   1   0
```

Adapt `1:10` to any value you'd like. Of course this only works if k is within reasonable range, otherwise this approach is suboptimal